# hierarchy level in relationship table in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table employee which has hierarchy data of manager and employee.

Sample data.

```
empId ManId
  101   100
  102   100
 1010   101
 1011   101
10101  1010
```

I need to find the level but it is not giving me correct output. I need an output like

```
level  Emp ID Man Id
1        101     100
1        102     100
2       1010     101
2       1011     101
3      10101    1010
```

Irrespective of the input as Emp ID or Man ID, the output should be constant. I am only getting the output when I am using  manager id as 100  but it doesnt work when i pass value as 10101

```
select distinct
level,
manager_id, 
employee_id
from employees
START WITH manager_id = 100
connect by   manager_id= prior employee_id
order by level
```

Comment: switch manager_id and employee_id in the connect by-clause

Answer (score 0):

START WITH clause is used to specify a root row for the hierarchy which is employee id with 101 value

Kindly use the below

```
select distinct
       level,
       manager_id, 
       employee_id
       from employees
       where level<=3
       START WITH employee_id = 101
       connect by   manager_id= prior employee_id
       order siblings by employee_id
```

**Update1:-**:-You can remove START WITH if root row is not specific

```
   select distinct
       level,
       manager_id, 
       employee_id
       from employees
       where level<=3
       connect by   manager_id= prior employee_id
       order siblings by employee_id
```

Check this link for more information
[Hierarchical Queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

Comment: If I dont have the root id and have the bottom id which is 1010, can i still get the required output?

Comment: you can manipulate the result if you know till what level you want the result in case of employee 1010 you can add where level <=3

Comment: It is not working. I am using the below query 
    
     select 

    manager_id, 

    employee_id,level

   from employees

    WHERE level <= 3

    connect by   prior employee_id =manager_id

    order by level

Comment: what is the result you are getting

Comment: is it possible to get the output without passing start with clause??
This is because it can happen that i need to get the level by passing input as 10101  which is not the manager here